# Check if string is in list with python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to check if a String is inside a list.

I have these two variables:

```
 new_filename: 'SOLICITUDES2_20201206.DAT'  (str type)
```

and

```
 downloaded_files:
   [['SOLICITUDES-20201207.TXT'], ['SOLICITUDES-20201015.TXT'], ['SOLICITUDES2_20201206.DAT']] (list type)
```

for checking if the string is inside the list, I'm using the following:

```
   if new_filename in downloaded_files:
       print(new_filename,'downloaded')
```

and I never get inside the if.

But if I do the same, but with hard-coded text, it works:

```
    if ['SOLICITUDES2_20201206.DAT'] in downloaded_files_list:
        print(new_filename,'downloaded')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `downloaded_files` is a list of lists. A list can contain anything insider it, numbers, list, dictionaries, strings and etc. If you are trying to find if your string is inside the list, the `if` statement will only look for identical matches, i.e., strings.

What I suggest you do is get all the strings into a list instead of a list of lists. You can do it using list comprehension:

```py
downloaded_files = [['SOLICITUDES-20201207.TXT'], ['SOLICITUDES-20201015.TXT'], ['SOLICITUDES2_20201206.DAT']]

downloaded_files_list = [file[0] for file in downloaded_files]
```

Then, your `if` statement should work:

```py
new_filename = 'SOLICITUDES2_20201206.DAT'

if new_filename in downloaded_files_list:
   print(new_filename,'downloaded')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is asking if a string is in a list of *lists of a single string each*, which is why it doesn't find any.